# Setting up Redirects for old pages

Tags: redirects, 301-redirect, godaddy

I have some old pages that for a website that are showing up in google search results. Until google reindexes the site, I want to redirect those urls to the new homepage.

Yet, when I go through GoDaddys redirect setup, I get a warning that the site and url must be on this account.

Example:

Old URL

```
http://www.example.com/oldpage.html
```

This url/page is no longer on the server. So it should redirect to

```
http://www.example.com/new-page.html
```

But as I said, GoDaddy throws an error. Any ideas? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about GoDaddy's error, other than maybe it is expecting `example.com` rather than `www.example.com` (although I doubt it)?! You don't actually need to specify the host if redirecting on the same site?

But anyway, this is easy to do in your root .htaccess file using mod_alias:

```
Redirect 301 /oldpage.html /new-page.html
```

(This assumes Apache 2.2.6+ for the ability to specify a root-relative, rather than absolute URL, as the target.)